# Nokia mystery puzzle

Tags: binary, puzzle-solver

A friend sent me this puzzle. I'm pretty sure solving it will require some programming. Can anyone crack it? The original is [here](http://www.otit.fi/mystery.txt) in case of encoding issues in the past below.

```
Did you know that...
List of prime numbers include 2 as only even number, but not 1 which is equally not divisible by any other number than itself and 1?
Indexes in most of the programming languages start from 0?
Random mess is often considered as just "life"?
Prime bits of life include open position in Nokia?
Start here:
QnšmzFyN\�Li�B§TJ�vhgUEg�XbDMb¯o�ag�wUF�Iv¶u²nGTbf�vFc�]n¡vbD^Q@utJjMthn wŸ�B�CiŸ`yuftlyF]^Qvfh¹ºK[fF�wXuHdojG�YftvTP�OwmU�gzF�zuYQ�Z[gEn�wjU�MmŽ`FDtœPC�Sw`�Raw^»DuFlVvUdEa@uiluigJQhgtc[ŒGVcBSUL�OtnouŠ�KwGTI hEtwžgtEAtl§wuZoE�Qvvc[wZ@¢Pu\T�fo[RXtGVU¶wCdySwU[{w��wGX\�\v^ŽBFS_v^^@yXPmctvPcoWvHlfBwI�FJGu�AbWcnuªOv@[j�tu@GwBNB[tX�USioimTC¶KQŸbv\iiYK£DQ�[Ich`Oš[vcwaOyJ\RoŸP�tMQvtEvLKºWbwBvtvQžf�kXv°A\TA¬�PPwU�eTT[NAIAFhvti{WOga{`H�tRJ{a`BMHUI[ZI`lIDb\BA�fa`mtd€gK\@BwCTeR�³ww�NFDCGvfQSz£t`FBZ¬wMevA^Rv¢^iSct¢Bk�\zjNBv¢tRbIwNv\¹E³tiBHxwCH«\mtt`­xgNBu@hJŸkeZbQŠaaF^o_YEcLii£F`tKjU_wHt��w®wDvO^²¶[DDvAvP�uk»gAOtx]JHRuWvcu�dQmŠn_\guZD]DlHh[€DGvfb@_X¬TMt^Xun@F«twOMTIv�]ZjvKSTwdRicvxG\K�¯mStILhUvOjwb^t�xi_VJUuRwh§v`Wg]W{JoŽh]uvIdw�@QXZ]«ŽinWJ�R_ZtwB¶Vu_JStI@UUMxT`²VYyuV�l\eW]lOghv]²NP\i�xySiuJvZG±ut�`\jMEtVZuv�twv±o_Awu�vn�oŽzYTM^fEt\bWH�M�lGilw�BI²tPgTvaE`h±e�x\aafvBNmt[RŠn£hjOBEUtmhNHtAuVHP�va_uOn�\UKnuBAHW_waFwH{WLu\ZRvT[nmvv«B]Yj�JbF¹BgyDNcv^`@iAwwlweFYlwe�§fk@mnPNh�Fg\`Di[�{j¬enk�Jw{Wh^[�cYO]`MWu®�oclQTg`X�VbnXlK\\ŠMuvAw]_^®SvTA�ZSmwB`PUwYw�»\utCnl[JGcuWVTXo€¬M¡aoPuvjR[jvV[�C_zM�nUn�wP«t¿IMVtuhwFJXvº@t^UEtIhGbCXt]bVSE€CMuZktmH_uvtwuIt¹vtKy{wNC«YivUM[BG�ntCJ^aBBFdhfNlPoBE@kuTe�VC�kRwwhZdTtfnt�^v^mg�cPeh�§Au°^BtND�Jd[f\th§`jNwRvFHLu@MNwvuSR`CdSE]vaaw_wPIvRjw^HXDi°fQ�wIfNTS`ttSA¢jv XX�EP@lbDALWdzkuG€_VQvmjIX�EkTummeC³iuZokw�]uQfMcBu�SXH_Whtuv^SjyejxoEtœwStoD�xVeaOA�jtJBa_KDPwtK^\ounwfZKDDuL@[vhIDI»tvvJc\cµvWe�FPvv�beWKUtaOtvA�DMTLcPh]nDD[Qfc�R�vwštAvhfWEv^hEZPuvaCNDBQtwdvuaw@�D@dPCG�wIdttYMKvau²wQnm^mOuvaZNB�viKBvkuDj¶BuVb_§hGtk­EZvSc�tttµ_GxwvGwŒ]U�[{KJcv�h�ŒKv¯vRQIPHOivFG©LtXvtljuIB\^v�zDiPBgtcm�@tUdetwYhQuvK§¥t[�HONFwcXDxH�w`t_J`�tcHXM`vO°wkQQttw§@t£uvI[TTRgvŠbf¡AJoWoRfT�dP�g�wi�S{wYYh¢uleHR@\�KnK³u\vNcx{FHkvwTMEwP�gngEvutdGOE[teWDµwKOdG�G^�wEGARcNYutf�tvmdutv@TvvF�QHkX�]tPbvšlwvVJwuKu�So@o©]LNLx�btvXGDdlLz@eVzCltvwvt�Vb£L²wPXh_viyOw[XEkSvEJdIvmVJuw�@VGTw�tjKhjv�uWmEUhI®TtwRiuŒFZ�lYtuH\\F�Ufšn®YSu�dšOk�xuVdDgmOIEBUdw@]kvtEYAt^�NutW®®ebtMhv\kfljk@±nLgEB[�fImIKt[[�jo¯OnMtwcfgKcŒuEEªvvN\�tEw`GvNQ[gUK_euho�oY[�WTKMBatvl^twJ¿cK^lAaHw�M_uFK�DvtfNªKw€šKnIv@FiI�vj°S±Ru@wid»Qt\uRvZDvZjkwuFQVH\�zW[�hMUUkNe^�famV�TGw[hJovbtugIw`t`BDwl�tlVwQmtQ^YnOA¡StuCiv�]µ€BJj`n�]BeYi[PLtY@mAoPxHxI�SwIiJ�LA±uMhPm[oPG¯OUHuKvlIbwNttX�w_k]gwmL_`m�Ef]AVvwuPiwNT±Œfw¢`XAAKuwBvkLVXNix®]lVGSo�b]XS�[foSn�]Hu®md[Lf�QJcY�ZtkŸBtjtvPH�MfYBFnLYty_dBTQzdwT@W�[uvFwama[oj@Zh�IBmYtPJEie¹�Bw]\wOwŠNdfNul^zSwwYuOu^u]`nm¬vBBvmDP^ZGRgtIxcZYbn�Dn\D¥`otŽi^E_BvD]_w u\w�EvimvuPGwH�ST^otQ¥u]�KU¥W[CR¯l@vjt€^ATNu¥HVªTvC�ifzwteG[[`gtFJŠK¡tjt�MNbkuSuMDU£lt^[E�tiLc{ZhFu`RX]tdXvYuXuTdAKvuaxPXfi[Wg]wAeukeQkuP�utvvVBExOjgi{ad`HtaiŒuvo^u@lN©Awbub\kDWµ\»WYuRYZFHR{QvojtyNbtvwDOIv_YnAu^wttunyu[VCOQWE^dTuwtuYUwl^�VXlGž�NNFk��``KQV\NWHG] ^RNkRVQw\JAO@@wdV�ev«tc[vLAZNMoYZQk�H�uFBOdt]c]ADKDfvfC[�u`®\tSX�vUDE^vu_e�JwOhmd]EMwiRHmUH]\W°vtHzWµ\@j]^mh{MAxnAPu\QuvQuekthoµRTwNX`uTcŸS_Bc�SZwJJwe_cye^ªNtwv�Wuu�ev�IQ¹B�Xt]Q_gbVkmXwh_XUL±»tvvId`wAgX�]bžmVumB«DlJ_G�D@egUoPtu�@i[S¥e\ŽFIMFweI`ut_wIOD«vZ[_wiGuVZKFk±PDG�Aw@^`vAoS{nvw``kXUSuuZWù
```

Comment: The challenge is over.
Thoughts are running through your mind:
"YES! I did it!"
"Was this all?"
"This was easy! I want more!"... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python - 132 chars

Data is read from stdin, starting from the "Qn..."

```
I=raw_input()
print("%X"%int("".join(`ord(I[x/8])>>(7-x%8)&1`*all(x%f for f in range(2,x))for x in range(2,24024)),2)).decode('hex')
```

Comment: How do I run it? Cmd.exe text encoding doesn't allow me to paste the text correctly

Comment: I just get a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: Me too /15chars

Comment: @John, M28, you'll have to copy it from the provided link, the version in the question doesn't work at all

Comment: Hmm..I'm still getting gibberish.

Comment: Me too, again :(

Comment: I also got gibberish at first. It was an encoding issue. Try this: `wget http://www.otit.fi/mystery.txt; sed '1,6d' mystery.txt | python nokia.py`

Comment: That was it the whole time?!?  -facepalm-  +1

Comment: What's the result?